# How to find the capacitance between two metal sheets

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electromagnetism, electrostatics, electric-circuits, capacitance

Let’s say I have two metal sheets in a 2D plane. The first one has area A, the second one is infinitely long, and they are separated from each other by a distance d. How can I find the capacitance between them? [image]

Comment: If all you need is a numerical value, there is a very easy to use electromagnetic simulation tool called FEMM. It beats everything else I know in simplicity and price (it's free but not open source, I believe).

Answer (score 1):

There is likely no closed-form solution.

A numerical approximation can be found by solving [Laplace's equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laplace%27s_equation) for the electrostatic potential by the finite elements method, using fixed values of the potential on the two electrodes as the boundary conditions.